# How to check if a form field is required?

Tags: django

Within my model I have defined a required field class like this:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(_(u"Last Name"), max_length=50)
```

For the form I am simply using the ModelForm to keep it simple:

```
class ContactsForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = Contact
```

I understand there are third-party-mods helping with rendering forms, however going plain for now to see when I hit the limitations, so I tried this:

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{form.last_name.label}}:
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{form.last_name}}
                    {% if  form.last_name.required %}(*){% endif %}
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Surprisingly I don't get to see the **(*)** even though its a required field.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is odd. When I face this strange things I always use the manage.py shell command. You can try that yourself creating an instance of your form and see if the field it's in fact required. Just for checking

Comment: @Kave, are you sure that `form.last_name` contains the attribute `required`. I am not sure but I don't think so.

Comment: machaku, I thought that would be automatically set, since the field can't be blank nor null. Do you set it yourself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't test this now, but I'm pretty sure you need `form.last_name.field.required` - `form.last_name` is an instance of `BoundField`, and it has a `field` property which points to the original `CharField`, which in turn contains the `required` property.

Answer (score 2):

If your field is an instance of BoundField then you can use property `required` of the `field`.
Lets say you iterate on the form for fields:
On each iteration you will have each field in order you put in the Form class.

So, the code for the Form class will look like this.

```py
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
```

And your iteration on the form in the template could look like this:

```py
...
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
    <label {% if field.field.required %}class="required"{% endif %}>{{ field.label }}</label>
{% endfor %}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think tou can override the default label for required fields. I mean something like

```
class ContactsForm(ModelForm):
   last_name = CharField(label='Last Name (*)')

   class Meta:
       model = Contact
```